# How can I implement the ability to scroll through CGRect's in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll

I am trying to have a scrollable app, right now I have multiple CGRect's being created by a for in function. Once they are all created and layed out, they exceed the screen view, but they are static and I can not scroll down to view the rest of them. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class Draw2dD: UIView {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //measuring the screen size
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    //creating background
    let background = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    background.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 220/255, blue: 117/255, alpha: 1)
    addSubview(background)

    for x in 0..<23 {

        // setting values to use in the code
        let rectWidth = screenWidth*0.98
        let rectHeight = rectWidth*0.2408163265
        let margin = Int(rectHeight*1.209039548)

        //Margin settings
        var yDis: Int
        yDis = x*margin+(margin-Int(rectHeight))

        //Building the rectangle and setting the color
        let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight))
        rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // Setting the margins
        var rectFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight)
        rectFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(screenWidth*0.01)
        rectFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(yDis)
        rectangle.frame = rectFrame

        // Rectangle border radius
        rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = 7

        addSubview(rectangle)

    }

}


}
```

And this is what it produces:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjwM2.png

How would I be able to scroll down through all of the CGRect's that were made?

Comment: why don't you use an `UITableView`?

Comment: Use `UIScrollView` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/